# Python 2.7.6 Optimizing code for packing big endian bytes into a string

Tags: python, struct, endianness

```
import struct

    varA['Z']['value'] = 8700
    varA['Y']['value'] = 8800
    varA['X']['value'] = 8900
    varA['W']['value'] = 8800
    varA['V']['value'] = 8700
    varB = ""
    varC = ""
    for name in 'Z Y X W V'.split(' '):
     varB = C[name]['value']
     varC += str(struct.pack('>h',varB))
    print varC[:-1] + '\n'
```

What i need is a string of bytes,
where each number is a signed int16 big-endian byte(s).

this code here works for what im trying to do, but i know
theres a far more elegant solution.

I wouldn't spend any time on optimizing the varA as its
only there to set up the code and won't be used in my project.
Also the print is also there to set up the problem, im actually
sending the bytes as a socket.

Initially I had this in an array first few times, but when I converted the
array to a bytearray, I kept running into having 0x00 mixed in.
Same with struct, as you can see in my solution removing the 
0x00 at the end.

Comment: Is it your desire to remove the `0x00` bytes entirely, so that each element packs to a single byte?

Comment: Each element packed to two bytes, in a string with no delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to do it. It's unclear from the question whether this is exactly the result you desire.

```
values = [varA[name]['value'] for name in 'ZYXWV']
varC = struct.pack('>'+str(len(values))+'h', *values)
```

Comment: It turns out that the padding at the end i was referring to was actually '\n' that i was sending through the socket.  so i was actually taking data off to make it fit the formatting. 

Rereading the notes for struct, padding is only automatically added in between structs.

To enjoy the fruits of your labor, you can view it here. Thanks for your assistance.

https://github.com/CymatiCorp/CyKit/blob/master/Python/Cyos.py